# How do I check if the mouse is over a certain circle without overlap?

Tags: processing

In my processing program, I have made several circles positioned randomly. I used the distance formula to calculate if the mouse is over a certain area.

However, this algorithm fails when circles overlap because it thinks the mouse is over both circles. What is a way to only detect if the mouse is on the circle on top?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how you are implementing it, but one option would be to give each of your circles an index.  Start at 0 and increment for each circle.  Then, when your algorithm checks the circles, only use the circle with the highest index value.

Comment: Thanks, that works! I'm now storing the circles as objects with a draw method and attaching an index to each one.